# Keyboard hides the custom cell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am having a custom  cell in my tableview, when showing keyboard some of my cell gets hidden behind the keyboard.

To fix this issue I have tried as below

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*) [[textField superview] superview];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.mySmlMsgTemplatesTbl indexPathForCell:cell];
    [self.mySmlMsgTemplatesTbl scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];


   // [self.mySmlMsgTemplatesTbl scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[self.mySmlMsgTemplatesTbl indexPathForCell:cell] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

But it seems to be not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try following code as I have shown below. I didn't try it but it should work.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{  
    CGPoint point = [self.tableView convertPoint:yourtextview.bounds.origin fromView:yourtextview];
    NSIndexPath* path = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Upto 4 rows it works as expected but not for 5,6,7 and so on. pls let me know

Comment: I think it should work. Did you check what's different after 4 rows? Please check your code and make out something because i need to develop one sample application to do that and you have already it. So find out something which is stoping you.

Comment: (Aside, purely for interest: if you wish to express the wish that you hope your post helps, then you would say "Hope this will help you", without the comma after _hope_. It doesn't make much sense to have the pause in there, as it then is not clear what the hope is for. That all said, as my edits hopefully make clear, we prefer questions to be succinct on Stack Overflow, so it is best not to add this at all.)

Answer (score 0):

If it is the last cell for example, this won't work. The tableview can't scroll that far up. You will need to resize the tableview frame or use it's contentInset property to resize it.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way. You could try to move the whole view up and down.

Hope this will help

```
#define     kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD    200.0


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField {
    [txtField addTarget:self action:@selector(setViewMovedUp:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
    [txtField addTarget:self action:@selector(setViewMovedDown:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
}

-(void)setViewMovedUp:(id)sender
{
if (isKeyboardAppeared) {
    return;
}

isKeyboardAppeared = YES;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; // if you want to slide up the view

CGRect rect = self.view.frame;

rect.origin.y -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
rect.size.height += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;

self.view.frame = rect;
[UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)setViewMovedDown:(id)sender
{
[self actionSaveRegistration];
if (!isKeyboardAppeared) {
    return;
}

isKeyboardAppeared = NO;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; 

CGRect rect = self.view.frame;

rect.origin.y += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
rect.size.height -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;

self.view.frame = rect;

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i do this type of app you just need the textFieldname or textfield tag ..and you can pgive the tag to textField with visiblecell...

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    if(textField.tag==3)
    {
        tableview.frame=CGRectMake(tableview.frame.origin.x, tableview.frame.origin.y-40,tableview.frame.size.width , tableview.frame.size.height+40);

    }
    else if(textField.tag==4)
    {
        tableview.frame=CGRectMake(tableview.frame.origin.x, tableview.frame.origin.y-40,tableview.frame.size.width , tableview.frame.size.height+40);
    }

}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField.tag==3)
    {
        tableview.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, 320,460);
        //tableview.frame=CGRectMake(tableview.frame.origin.x, tableview.frame.origin.y+70,tableview.frame.size.width , tableview.frame.size.height-70); 
    }
    else if(textField.tag==4)
    {
        tableview.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, 320,460);
        //tableview.frame=CGRectMake(tableview.frame.origin.x, tableview.frame.origin.y+70,tableview.frame.size.width , tableview.frame.size.height-70);    
    }
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    if(textField.tag==3)
    {
        tableview.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, 320,460);
        //scrollview.frame=CGRectMake(tableview.frame.origin.x, tableview.frame.origin.y+70,tableview.frame.size.width , tableview.frame.size.height-70);   
    }
    else if(textField.tag==4)
    {
        tableview.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, 320,460);
        //tableview.frame=CGRectMake(scrollview.frame.origin.x, tableview.frame.origin.y-70,tableview.frame.size.width , tableview.frame.size.height+70); 
    }

}
```

i use here scrollView for Registration form here not a perfect code which you want but i think you can get idea from this code...
Hope,this help you..
:)